# From java code file getting created with a lock symbol in Linux

Tags: java, linux

From java, I use the following code to create a file:

```
File dirName = new File("/var/www/html/nyk/app/webroot/MusicDB/music.db");
```

But the file gets created with a 'lock symbol' on top of it which indicates restricted permissions. I am able to change the permissions of this file manually from terminal using `cgmod -R 777 filename` . But I am using another code in the same program, which copies the created file to another destination. Due to the restricted permission, it is not able to copy the file.

How can I create the file eliminating the restricted permsiion issue in first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
myFile.setReadable(true);
myFile.setWritable(true);
```

Comment: yes, I have tried that before posting here. It does not change the lock symbol and hence I cannot copy file

Comment: in that case, try __myFile.setReadable(true, false)__ and __myFile.setWritable(true, false)__

Comment: no luck with `myFile.setReadable(true, false) and myFile.setWritable(true, false)`!

Comment: are you sure you quite sure you are creating the file and that doesn't exist before you create your __File__ object?

Comment: Sorry, now that I noticed `myFile.setReadable(true, false) and myFile.setWritable(true, false) ` worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `umask` outside of Java before starting the application.

```
umask 000
```

or use

```
dirName.setReadable(true);
dirName.setWritable(true);
```

Comment: What about either changing the umask or the permission directly on the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`File.setReadable()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadable%28boolean%29), [`File.setWritable()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setWritable%28boolean%29) methods for that! You can either grant the permission, or revoke them as per your needs! Currently in your case, you need to provide `true` to grant the permissions!

Or a dirty workaround would be

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 file")
```